# Canonical Pose of PointCloud

Tags: object, linear-algebra, eigen, point-cloud-library

I made a strange observation and I'm asking myself if someone has an explaination.

Suppose we have PointCloud, for example a perfect cylinder. This cylinder is somehow placed and rotated in space. Now for this cylinder we compute it's centroid and eigenvectors with a principal component analysis.

Now I can describe it's pose as an affine transformation of the form:

```
Eigen::Affine3d pose;
pose.translation << centroid[0], centroid[1], centroid[2];
pose.linear() = evecs;
```

Now let's assume I want to transform the object in it's unambiguous, canonical pose, then I would do the following:

```
obj.transform(obj.getPose().inverse());
```

By this I would transform the object into it's local coordinate system and thus it's canonical pose. And `obj.getPose()` would construct me it's new pose, again after recomputing it's new eigenvectors and centroid position (which then should be in (0,0,0)).

After I did this, however it ended up the object's new, canonical pose was sometimes this:

```
1 0 0 0
0 1 0 0
0 0 1 0
0 0 0 1
```

So the identity matrix. I would have expected this, but sometimes I got this:

```
-1  0  0  0
 0 -1  0  0
 0  0  1  0
 0  0  0  1
```

I can't really explain this behaviour to myself and I it's causing problems for me as I'm comparing poses. Do you have an idea why this is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eigen vectors are not uniquely defined, if `v` is an eigenvector then `-v` is also an eigenvector. This is exactly what you observe.

Moreover, if you have a perfectly symmetric cylinder, then two eigenvalues should be equal, and the two respective eigenvectors can be arbitrarily chosen as a pair of orthogonal vectors within the plane orthogonal to the third eigenvector (axis of the cylinder).

Comment: Yeah I had a deeper look and you are correct. Is it a proper way to go to just assign the Identity-Matrix after transforming in canonical pose? To get rid of this problem?

Comment: yes of course! But in the more general case where you want to compare two poses, then you have to be careful about the aforementioned ambiguities.